# Unable to Update Values in SQL Server from DF in R

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

Want update values in a SQL Server database, but values are not updating.

The code runs without any error.

```
# Df is like supp_pivot:

DateID     Buyer  Supplier  Rel    Res   Agl
--------------------------------------------
20210414    1        21     0.74  0.53  0.82
.
.
.
-------------------------------------------
#Code:

db <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("DRIVER={SQL Server};
                                 server=",my_server,";
                                 database=",my_db,";
                                 uid=",my_username,";
                                 pwd=",my_pwd))


for(row in 1:nrow(supp_pivot)){
  query <- paste0(
     "UPDATE rawcalculations SET Res = " ,supp_pivot$Res[row], 
     "Rel = " ,supp_pivot$Rel[row],  
     "Agl = " ,supp_pivot$Agl[row],  
     "WHERE DateID = " ,supp_pivot$DateID[row], 
     "BuyerID = " ,supp_pivot$Buyer[row],
     "SupplierID = " ,supp_pivot$suppliers[row]
  )
  sqlQuery(db, query)
}
```

Not getting any error but data not updated in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temporary table and execute the update in a single query:

```
# Create temporary table
sqlSave(db, supp_pivot, tablename = "#TEMP")

query <-"
UPDATE rawcalculations 
SET rawcalculations.Res = t.Res, 
    rawcalculations.Rel = t.Rel,  
    rawcalculations.Agl = t.Agl  
FROM
    rawcalculations
INNER JOIN
    #TEMP t
ON 
rawcalculations.DateID = t.DateID, 
rawcalculations.BuyerID = t.Buyer,
rawcalculations.SupplierID = t.suppliers;" 

sqlQuery(db, query)

#Remove temporary table
sqlQuery(db,"DROP TABLE #TEMP")
```

Note that after creation of the temporary table you can for debugging purposes check which rows should be updated:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    rawcalculations
INNER JOIN
    #TEMP t
ON 
rawcalculations.DateID = t.DateID, 
rawcalculations.BuyerID = t.Buyer,
rawcalculations.SupplierID = t.suppliers;
```